# How to install ror on apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

Is all I need mod_rails and ruby 1.9.2? What is the best resource for production setup of rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first time I deployed a Rails app, I simply [read this](http://www.modrails.com/install.html).

Once this config done, I recommend you learn how to use [capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/).

Comment: passenger is what it is referred as

Comment: @Pierre: I don't really understand your comment since Passenger = mod_rails

Comment: that's what I am saying, just wanted to have the passenger keyword appear somewhere in the answer :)